Changing background color of button alters other button styles in .NET MAUI
I just (finally) upgraded an application from Xamarin to MAUI. After doing the upgrade, I found that any background color (other than the default) applied to a button causes the button to grow in vertical size, as well as have an ugly white box around it with a box shadow. This is true throughout my entire application, but here's an example:

This is the code that I have to display those buttons. As you can see, the strange styling happens both when I have the "BackgroundStyle" attribute set on the page itself (green), as well as when the attribute is set in my App.xaml file (red/danger).
<Grid x:Name="coordinatorSection">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button IsVisible="{Binding ShowConfirm}" Text="Confirm" FontSize="Medium" Clicked="ConfirmClicked" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" BackgroundColor="#218838" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="{Binding ShowDeny}" Text="Deny" FontSize="Medium" Clicked="DenyClicked" Style="{StaticResource dangerButtonStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
    <Button IsVisible="{Binding ShowTentative}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="#e0a800" Text="Tentative" FontSize="Medium" Clicked="TentativeClicked" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Text="Message Requester"  FontSize="Medium" Clicked="MessageRequesterClicked" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Text="Edit Request"  FontSize="Medium" Clicked="EditRequestClicked" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
</Grid>

These are the relevant portions of my App.xaml file:
            <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily">
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto-Black" />
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto-Regular" />
                        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="secondaryButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily">
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto-Black" />
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto-Regular" />
                        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 0, 0">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="dangerButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#dc3545" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily">
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto-Black" />
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto-Regular" />
                        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 0, 0">
                </Setter>
            </Style>

Finally, my styles.xml:
<resources>

    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/material_grey_300</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#1ca497</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#1ca497</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#1ca497</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DatePickerDialogButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DatePickerDialogButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#1ca497</item>
    </style>

</resources>



I've tried explicitly setting the border and shadow properties, but that only adds additional borders and shadows to these strange white boxes.
The problem only occurs on buttons with a specifically set background color. The default (primary) colored buttons are as expected.
I've tried setting both the Background and BackgroundColor attributes; the same result happens.
This happens even if I make a new button, and then set the background color on it.

I would greatly appreciate any help or direction with this. I'll gladly provide more code, examples, or details about the problem. Thanks in advance.

it would be really easy for us to diagnose this if you can create a sample project on GitHub that replicates this issue, I would love to take a look at it

Sure thing - I'll work on getting one spun up. I have a feeling that when I create a brand new project, the issue won't happen, but I'll try getting one set up and posting it here.

Indeed, upon creating a new project and pasting in my App.xaml and other code, the issue doesn't happen. I'm afraid I can't make the entire repository public. If there's any other code I can provide that would be helpful I will, otherwise if there's just not enough information to solve the problem, I understand. If there are directions you'd recommend to investigate, though, I'd still appreciate it.

What version of .NET MAUI are you using and what's the version of Microsoft.Maui.Controls in your app?
Another thing I would check is if any of these buttons have something that is making changes to its Background property on runtime somehow (Some global style) may be it could be on its parent too

Also you have a lot of XF style code still and I think you should read this https://blog.stackademic.com/increasing-performance-in-a-net-maui-application-2be8ce7d995a

I appreciate the responses, @FreakyAli. When I ran dotnet workload list, I got this: maui-windows | Manifest Version: 8.0.7/8.0.100 | Installation Source: VS 17.9.34728.123. Also, I appreciate the article recommendation. I was just assigned maintenance on this app a few days ago and have never touched xamarin/maui or any mobile work before, so the help is very valuable to me.

Oh, and Microsoft.Maui.Controls is set to Version="$(MauiVersion)" in my App.xaml.

I am happy this helped man, Also it's good you were able to update things to the latest and aren't facing any issues

Not sure that anyone would ever have this problem again, but just in case, it was resolved after I updated Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility to the latest versions, a solution hinted at by @FreakyAli.
